# jquery conflict with hoverIntent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a site that has been working fine however recently we added a form to a specific page. This form was built by someone else and uses javascript/jQuery to process.

Upon adding this form it has broken most of the other jquery on the page, namely the dropdown menu plugin.

This is only happening on the below page:
http://agovo.co.uk/crm-and-sales/crm-sales/bpmonline/

The console error is:

> TypeError: $(...).hoverIntent is not a function

But I noticed it has broken the slide out box to the right of the site. and these errors do not happen on other pages.

I realise there is jquery loaded twice, one if by WP and the other is manually, if i remove the manually added one it breaks everything so im not sure what the jquery one is doing!

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: use  jQuery(".dropdown li").hoverIntent( config );

Comment: The hover Intent is brought in by the plugin so i'm not able to change that?

Answer (score 1):

You're loading two different versions of jQuery on your page (1.11.1 first, and then 1.10.2).

Every script tag that contains a plugin that occurs after the first version, but before the second version, will be "overwritten" (and you'll see the error you are getting above).

Please only ever include one version of jQuery on your page.

Comment: If you read my original post if i remove the second version it breaks everything.

Comment: You are loading `jQuery` hoverIntent script in your footer, but it is being used in your header - before the script has been declared.

Answer (score 0):

I added no conflict to the form jQuery and it works fine now.